# Why isn't my freezer getting cold?

Tags: refrigerator

My freezer stopped freezing.  There was ice on the evaporator coil.  I cleared that.  All fans and compressor are running.  I replaced the relay and capacitor.  The refrigerator is cold to the touch from the outside and cool on the inside. what should I do next?

Answer (score 3):

Ice buildup on the evaporator is a sign of a low refrigerant charge. To verify this is the problem I would defrost the unit first, it could also be a bad defrost timer or a fan that died or even bad door seals. Since we don’t know the model or type all are guesses but these are the common problems.

If you defrost the coil and it immediately comes back (I mean in a couple of hours) low refrigerant charge is the most common issue. If after defrosting it takes several days to ice up I would be checking the door seals, fan and defrost timer.

I have found newer fridge/freezers do not last like they used to. I have found adding a service port and recharging brings the unit back to life for a few more years--I almost never find any leaks but believe there must be some that are smaller than my leak checkers can detect.  With these once the problem occurs I have found in 3-5 more years they do it again.  The lucky thing with r134a I have found is the charge is quite small many times less than a pound so it is easily fixed or topped off.

Comment: Maybe pedantic, but "[Freon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freon)" is a brand name of the old CFC product that's not used anymore because it seriously damaged our atmosphere. That isn't what we're talking about anymore. You probably know this, but it's better to use generic terms for full understanding by readers.

Comment: I have to disagree I have a brand new jug Freon R134a is the name. yes this is a trademark but it is still quite common, R134a is the ingredient in duster canisters and is designed to be released into the atmosphere, but use it for hvac and you need a license. R134a is the most common refrigerant used in Fridge & freezers. As most people have no clue what CFC, hcfc , hfc & hfo refrigerants are it is easier to say Freon in my professional opinion. I hold a universal 608 and 609 epa licenses, I find it funny that most of the folks that have an issue with the word Freon don’t have a license.

Comment: That would be because most people don't have licenses, period, but I take your point.